# Decimal Times in Excel not Reformatting to Standard Display

Tags: excel, ms-access, formatting

I currently have several worksheets that are populated by queries I have linked to an Access database. Currently, they are retrieving times and other data from another worksheet and are linked through Access. However, the times are displaying only as the decimal times that Excel uses. I've tried reformatting the columns, but that hasn't worked. However, all the math I've done on them *is* presentable in the proper time format, which for me is *hh:mm:ss*.

I also know that the decimal data *is* convertible to the proper time format; for example, (0.40048611111) is the decimal format for 9:36:42 AM, which is what the source data says, but the executed query only displays the decimal.

The worksheet that the queries are linked to is in the same workbook as the worksheets containing the queries, as well. Could this be causing any issues? It would be preferable to keep them both in the same workbook.

Thanks!

Comment: I fit it not changing then the numbers are being brought over as text.  How is the link being made?  Try to convert at that time to a number.

Comment: @ScottCraner The link is being made through Access - I have linked from the workbook **W** a worksheet **A** to Access. Then, I have linked queries from the access database file back to **W** in different worksheets. Unfortunately Access won't let me change anything relating to the values of columns, as it is a linked worksheet, and changing the type of the column in Excel did not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a plain *select* query to convert and clean your linked data:

```
Select 
    CVDate([YourExcelDateField]) As TrueDate,
    SomeField As FieldNameOne,
    AnotherField
From
    YourLinkedExcelTable
```

Then use this query, not the linked Excel table, for the further processing.

Comment: Solved! Thanks so much.